# Doctype printed on the page content

Tags: content

Strange problem on the site. WordPress template is GoodLife - Responsive Magazine & Newspaper Theme

Even after disabling all plugins and changing WordPress template nothing changed

It appears on the Page only. If the Page is empty everything is ok

Probably this is WordPress core bug

```
<div class="post post-detail post-13789 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-13789">
    <div class="post-content">
        <p>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
            <br/>
            <html>
                <body>
        </p>
        <div class="row row row-fluid">
```

WordPress Version 4.9.7
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I mean, it just looks like that’s been put into the page content. Have you checked the text view?

Comment: Are you using a page builder of any kind? I can say very confidently that WordPress core does not have a bug that adds the doctype (an outdated one at that) to page content.

Comment: I use Visual Composer. But even when the plugin is disabled this bug still appears